# Adding a button to form

Tags: html

```
<form class="user" method="POST" action="{{ url('login') }}?next={{next_url}}">
   {{ csrf_token()|raw }}
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" name="email" required="required" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="{{ _('Enter Email Address...') }}">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="password" required="required" autocomplete="false" id="password" placeholder="{{ _('Password') }}">
   </div>
   <button type="submit">
   {{_("Login")}}
   </button>
</form>
```

I need to add a button for register (example.com/register) below the login button. But when I add that when the user clicks on the Register button, It says that Email and password fields are required. How to resolve this issue?

Register button code: `<button href="{{ url('register') }}">{{_("Create an Account!")}}</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `button` tag can be of 3 types: `submit`, `reset` and `button`. If you do not specify the type it will default to `submit`. If the `button` then happens to be inside a `form`, it will try to submit it, hence the error you are getting.

There are a couple options you have here:

- Specify the type of the `button`:

  ```
  <button type="button" href="{{url('register')}}">{{_("Create an Account!")}}</button>
  ```
- Put the `button` outside the `form`:

  ```
  <form>
  </form>
  <button ....>
  ```
- Use `e.preventDefault()` in `javascript` if you have an `onclick` method for the `button`:

  ```
  function buttonClick(e) {
      e.preventDefault();  // this will prevent the default behavior of a submit
                           // button which is to submit a form
      // ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Set type to `button` instead of `submit` (default value).

```
 <button type="button">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a seperate `Form`

```
<form action="{{ url('register') }}"
    <button type="submit">Create an Account!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution if you are using **MVC**.

You can create the button in your Function register (Controller) then just call it to form

**Controller**: `<div class=\"col-lg-5  col-xs-5\"> <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-block' id='register' > Create Account </button> </div>`

```
$data['btn']=$btn;
```

**View**:

```
<form>
     <?=@$btn ?>
</form>
```

---

Or just do other form

```
<form> 
 <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-block' id='register'> Create Account</button>
</form>
```